# mongodb : group array elements by every n elements

Tags: mongodb

i have a data in mongodb:

```
    {
        "_id" : abc,

        "someField" : [ 
            11.5, 
            8, 
            7, 
            9, 
            9.5, 
            5, 
            5.5, 
            10, 
            8, 
            9, 
            5, 
            6, 
            8, 
            8.5, 
            3.5, 
            4, 
            11.5, 
            6, 
            5.5, 
            8, 
            10.5, 
            10.5, 
            5.5, 
            4, 
            11.5, 
            9.5, 
            8.5, 
            4.5 ],
firstDate : ISODate("2017-03-10T12:00:00.000Z")
    }
```

I use indexes to get the certain dates using firstdate. 
data is being stored every six hours,
 can i group this data by every 4 values as it will be a day.
 
After aggregation, It should be :

```
   {
        "_id" : abc,

        "someField" : [ 
            11.5, 
            10, 
            9,
            8.5,
            11.5,
            10.5,
            11.5
              ]
}
```

Comment: Could you show expected output format ?

Comment: hi, @mickl , i have edited the question.

Comment: hey @Soni007 it looks like you've pasted first 8 elements but based on your description (and title) it seems like you want to perform some grouping. Please provide how exactly this algorithm should work and I bet someone will help you :)

Comment: hi, @mickl, these elements itself should be grouped by for example maximum, so the first element should be : "11.5" from 11.5,8,7,9 then second element would be : "9.5" from 9.5,  5, 5.5, 10. So basically take maximum from every 4 values in field, thanks.

Comment: show the output you want

Comment: @AshishChoudhary, i have edited the question.

Comment: Looks like you could simplify the problem greatly by simply storing the values "per day" in the first place rather that collecting to an array for a "week". If you make some changes to your data collection code then aggregating will simply not be necessary, and if you do have a "reporting" need for other date periods it would be so much easier. So changing the recorded structure here is by far the superior approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can below following aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $match:  { _id: "abc" } },
    {
        $project: {
            items: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $ceil: { $divide: [ { $size: "$someField" }, 4 ] } } ]  },
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $max: {
                            $slice: [ "$someField", { $multiply: [ "$$index", 4 ] }, 4 ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

`$map` takes an array of `7` elements in this case which is [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) of an array divided by 4. So you'll get `[0,1,2 .., 7]`. Then you can use that array as an input of [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get 4-element arrays. Every array can be an input of [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/max/index.html).

As a result you'll get:

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "items" : [ 11.5, 10, 9, 8.5, 11.5, 10.5, 11.5 ] }
```

Comment: remove the first line `{ _id: "abc" },` or put `$match`

Comment: Really should add a `$cond` in case the array is under 4 elements to avoid an error, but `$range` is the correct way to get an artificial index. Pity that there isn't a constant variable like `$$INDEX` exposed on either `$map` or `$reduce`, because both operators "do" track that value internally. But without that being exposed you use `$range` just like here.

Comment: The only "then again" of course is the context of the question gives that data as clearly being for a "week". Therefore the array **always** has 28 entries, so it's not really necessary to get the size since it should be implied.

Comment: hi, @NeilLunn, data here shown for a week is for only example purpose, data we store is from 2016 to up to date, the need was to calculate and store for every six hours, then i thought it could be useful if we show as a day as well, thanks :)